# Requesting in a more subtle/formal manner

Tags: phrases, synonyms, word-usage, formality, email

I am writing a formal email. In the end, it goes like this:

> If this..... were to happen, **then it would be great**.

I am actually asking sth which I am not entitled to and depends entirely upon the receiver to consider it.

So, this is a request, and if accepted it would mean a lot to me (yes, I mean it).

I wish to write in a more subtle way. I wish to change "**it would be great**" to a more formal manner.

Comment: ... or possibly Interpersonal Skills SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Could you please give me a few examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What are the options that you tried? There are several variants to choose from. A few are:

1. It would mean a lot to me.
2. I would be much obliged if.
3. I would be indebted to you.
4. I'd appreciate it if.
5. I would be grateful to you.

Hope this helps.

NS